# Developing Depth-to-Water Index to predict wetlands

Tags: qgis

I am new to GIS modeling. I have recently been trying to produce a predictive wetland model and I have been exploring different methods. I have found the SAGA Wetness Index is quite effective in predicting wetland areas but I would like to learn how to develop a depth-to-water index as described in this paper below:

> Using the Cartographic Depth-to-Water Index to Locate Small Streams
> and Associated Wet Areas across Landscapes
>
> Barry White,Jae Ogilvie,David M.H. M.H. Campbell,Douglas Hiltz,Brian
> Gauthier,H. Kyle H. Chisholm, show all
>
> Pages 333-347 | Published online: 23 Jan 2013

There was a question a few years back where some people touched on the subject (link: [Cartographic Depth-To-Water method using Cost/Path Distance](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325387/cartographic-depth-to-water-method-using-cost-path-distance)) but I was hoping someone may be able to guide me/provide a step-by-step method on how to make this work. In previous posts it was suggested the following method are to be used:

- Generate a Degree slope map
- Convert to radians in Raster Calculator: [SlopeDeg] * 0.017453 (equivalent of Degrees * Pi/180)
- Convert output to Tangent in Raster Calculator: Tan([SlopeRadians]) (these two steps could be integrated in a single equation: Tan([SlopeDeg] * 0.017453)
- Use the output as the cost raster in CostDistance from water sources.

I am using QGIS and I don't have the Cost Distance tool, I have Cost Path (not sure if they are different). The issue is if I use the cost path it asks for start and end points.

Is there a tool on QGIS I can use for line data?

My source data would be streams and the cost raster would be slope.

Comment: Please provide a link to the earlier Q&A that you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you. I added the link.